# SFTP user login details real-time filtering

Tags: mysql, shell-script, sed, awk, syslog

I have enabled the SFTP login log into the default logfile `/var/log/syslog` and tried to filter the login time of each user and insert it into the database.

But the filtering is not worked as I expected.

Sample log file:

```
Jun 23 15:47:03 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24938]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jun 23 15:47:03 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24938]: Starting Exit the Session..c.
Jun 23 15:47:03 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24938]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 24980 (kill).
Jun 23 15:47:03 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1051.
Jun 23 15:47:03 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of nidasu.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of ftpuser1.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1069...
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[1]: Started Session 11907571 of user ftpuser1.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Reached target Paths.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Reached target Timers.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Reached target Sockets.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Reached target Basic System.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Reached target Default.
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[24987]: Startup finished in 15ms.
```

Needs to filter user login messages, like:

```
Jun 23 15:47:13 ip-172-16-0-62 systemd[1]: Started Session 11907571 of user ftpuser1.
```

I need to grep it out by matching the string "Started Session `11907571` of user `ftpuser1`"

The session number `11907571` is a random number and usernames also differ so grepping can ignore the numbers and usernames, only need to check the string like: **"Started Session *** of user ***"

And need to parse the line and `grep` the `date + time`, and username then insert it into the MySQL database.

If there is any option to create a daemon process to run and insert the details into DB, it will help me to do the task.

Comment: See: [MySQL import from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12968715/3776858)